# display:table, add another thead over column thead

Tags: html, jsp, displaytag

I'm using a `display:table` to view some report data on a jsp page. I want to use it to exploit the csv/excel export of display table tag. I need to add over the columns header with column name another header, that connect logically the column under it. This is an example:

```
           +--------------------------------------------+
           |            File               ||   Record  |
           +--------------------------------------------+
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Sort id ||Col1  ||  col2  || ...  || Coln||col1||coln |
+------------------------------------+------------------+
```

I tried to use a `display:caption` with the following code as first object into display table node:

```
<display:caption>
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="background: white" colspan="1"></th>
        <th class="header" colspan="8">File</th>
        <th class="header" colspan="1">Record</th>
    </tr>   
</display:caption>
```

It add the column, but under the column name thead :( :

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Sort id  |Col1  ||  col2  || ...   | Coln||col1||coln |
+------------------------------------+------------------+
           +--------------------------------------------+
           |            File               ||   Record  |
           +--------------------------------------------+
```

Somebody know if is possible to inject into `thead` automatically generated by display table tag html code to insert a `thead` over, or insert in some other way a row over the columns row name header?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood the question. Can you create a codepen with the code? But i think that `<thead>` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. Adding in display caption the header that i want enclosed into thead node, it add over column display thead:

```
<display:caption>
  **<thead>**    
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="background: white" colspan="1"></th>
        <th class="header" colspan="8">File</th>
        <th class="header" colspan="1">Record</th>
    </tr>
  **</thead>**
</display:caption>
```

I do not love this solution, but it works!